# Improve the model prediction time in huggingface transformer models without GPU

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

I am using huggingface transformers models for quite a few tasks, it works good but the only problem is the response time. It takes around 6-7 seconds to generate result while some times it even takes around 15-20 seconds. I tried on google collab using GPU, the performance in GPU is too fast within just a seconds it processes the result. As there is a limitation of GPU on my current server is there any way to increase the response time of the models using CPU only.

Currently using Text Summarization using GooglePegasus Model.
https://huggingface.co/google/pegasus-xsum

And Parrot Paraphrasing : which internally uses bert model from transformers
https://huggingface.co/prithivida/parrot_paraphraser_on_T5

Here is the code for Pegasus Model:

```
from transformers import PegasusTokenizer, TFPegasusForConditionalGeneration

model = TFPegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('google/pegasus-xsum')
tokenizer = PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained('google/pegasus-xsum')

ARTICLE_TO_SUMMARIZE = (
"This is text to summarize"
)
inputs = tokenizer([ARTICLE_TO_SUMMARIZE], max_length=1024, return_tensors='tf')

# Generate Summary
summary_ids = model.generate(inputs['input_ids'])
print([tokenizer.decode(g, skip_special_tokens=True, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=False) for g in summary_ids])
```

slight improvement will also help!

Comment: Also, Huggingface has published two very comprehensive articles on CPU inferencing (depending on your task, you might need training speed-up as well?), [here](https://huggingface.co/blog/bert-cpu-scaling-part-1) and [an older article here](https://medium.com/huggingface/benchmarking-transformers-pytorch-and-tensorflow-e2917fb891c2).

Comment: @dennlinger well training is not a concern, I am using already trained models, so need to optimise the performance when using the model.